# Как к кнопке меню привязать действие?

Tags: python, pyqt, qt-designer, qaction, menubar

Хочу, чтобы при нажатии на кнопку меню  **`"Выход"`** программа закрывалась.

Но, пока что удается сделать это только для подменю, т.к. они интерпретируются как `QAction`, а сам "Выход" нет.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как я могу это сделать? 
Либо в *Qt Designer* либо кодом.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> void QMenu::**aboutToShow**()
>
> Этот сигнал излучается непосредственно перед тем, как меню отображается пользователю.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, \
    QAction, qApp, QTextEdit

        
class MenuDemo(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()        

        bar = self.menuBar()

        file = bar.addMenu('File')
        quit = bar.addMenu('Quit')

        open_action = QAction('Open', self)
        open_action.setShortcut('Ctrl+O')
        save_action = QAction('Save', self)
        save_action.setShortcut('Ctrl+S')

        file.addAction(open_action)
        file.addAction(save_action)
        file.triggered.connect(self.selected) 
        
        quit.aboutToShow.connect(app.quit)         #
        #quit.aboutToShow.connect(exit)            # или так

    def selected(self, q):
        print(q.text() + ' selected')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MenuDemo()
    w.resize(600, 400)
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]