# Как создать слот для вызова пункта меню в PySide6?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyside6

Имеется панель навигации в программе на PySide6 + python. В неё входят пункты и подпункты. Как вызвать слоты для подпунктов я разобрался, но вот как вызвать слот при нажатии на сам главный пункт меню - не понятно. По аналогии с подпунктами не работает.

Например, мне нужно вызвать действие на нажатии 'О программе'(menu_about).
Аналогия вызовов с подпунктами не срабатывает.

Структура меню инструментов в QT Designer
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код как вызываю подпункты:

```
self.ui.menu_account_main.triggered.connect(
    lambda: self.on_user_select_menu_toolbars(PAGE_ID.PAGE_ACCOUNT_MAIN))
self.ui.menu_account_config.triggered.connect(
    lambda: self.on_user_select_menu_toolbars(PAGE_ID.PAGE_ACCOUNT_CONFIG))
self.ui.menu_account_exit.triggered.connect(
    lambda: self.on_user_select_menu_toolbars(PAGE_ID.PAGE_ACCOUNT_LOGOUT))
```

Comment: Нашёл ответ на подобную тему. Странно, что не наткнулся раньше. Решение:
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1337183/%D0%9C%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%82%D0%BE-%D0%BA-%D0%BA%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BA%D0%B5-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8E-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B2%D1%8F%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B5